# Bulk import images & create nodes

Tags: media, importing-exporting, batch-operations

Is there a way to bulk import images from server and auto create nodes for each image? this is for Drupal 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module [Bulk Media Upload](https://drupal.org/project/bulk_media_upload) is the one that I have used in the past for that matter. From the module page:

> With Bulk Media Upload you can upload a bunch of files and a new node, taxonomy term, or other entity will be created for every file. The files are selected via a browser file upload dialog and can be stored in a file or image field.
>   Also default values can be chosen for the other fields assigned to the new node.

I believe you will not have any difficulties, it is pretty straightforward. Also, if you come across some minor bugs, I have a couple of patches commited in its [issue queue](https://drupal.org/project/issues/bulk_media_upload?categories=All) awaiting community review.

Alternatively, one can use the [Feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds) module to import nodes. That would be more helpful with existing files. It might require to list the files into a CSV file (for *nix systems copy/paste from terminal the output of `ls /path/to/files`).

Comment: The only problem with that module is it can't import existing files.I'd have to upload on the go. Is there any tricks to select existing files?

Comment: For existing files a possibility is to use the [Feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds) module to import nodes, maybe along with some columns in a CSV file.